# How to create different modal bodies for mutliple tabs in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-modal, mat-tab

I implemented mat-tabs in Angular and want to open a modal (with ng-bootstrap) in every tab and it works. But all the modals contain the same modal-body and I can't change it. What do I have to do so that I can individualize every modal-body in each tab?

This is my code. Sorry if it is unclear. My problem is that the body of the modal stays  always the same for each tab, the rest part of the modal can stay the same so that´s no problem.

```
[html]

<h1>header text</h1> 
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="100ms"  [color]="'warn'">

<mat-tab label="test1"> <p> test1 </p>  <div class="border"> <button class="my- 
class" (click)="open(content)"> button 1 </button> </div> <ng-template #content 
let-modal>
 <div class="modal-header">
 <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">test1</h4>
 <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" 
(click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
 </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
 test body 1
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save 
click')">test1</button>
</div>
</ng-template> 
</mat-tab>



  <mat-tab label="test 2"> <p> test2 </p> 
  <div class="border"> 
   <button class="my-class" (click)="open(content)"> button 2 </button> 
  </div> <ng-template #content let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
   <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">test1</h4>
   <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" 
 (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
    test body 2
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save 
click')">test1</button>
 </div>
</ng-template>  
</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>


[Typescript]

export class MainboxComponent implements OnInit {

closeResult!: string;
constructor(
private modalService: NgbModal,  ) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
}

open(content: any) {
this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic- 
title'}).result.then((result) => {
  this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
}, (reason) => {
  this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
});
}

private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
  return 'by pressing ESC';
 } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
  return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
} else {
  return `with: ${reason}`;
}
}
```

Comment: You seem to be passing the same ‘content’ to open everytime..?

Comment: How can I change it?